# How can I search a text in some website (not from the source) with Python?

Tags: python

I want to make an "autofill" that works like this:

The site contains the Name and down the Name has the field to write it.

So, I want to make a program the search the "Name" in the website, and before that, click down the "Name" and write the name (easy part)...

How can I search for it?

I can't use the site forms, because, everysite has different forms

Comment: How do you want to access this web site? It sounds to me like you want something like [GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) and write your own script for it.

Comment: I want to access an expecific site with any internet browser (firefox, chrome, ie)... Its like, searching for a text in the site and verifying if it is "name", for example, then, if it is, click above and do the rest.

Comment: Have you checked into the urllib and urllib2 libraries?  They're designed to assist with http requests.

Comment: Yes, but I have to do it from a browser, Firefox expecificly

Comment: To control your browser remotely you could use Selenium RC. Here's getting started http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/getting-started-with-selenium-and-python.html

Comment: its there another way? someway to select to select the text and verify if its what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: [Automate firefox with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152/automate-firefox-with-python) and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7620

Comment: it's there another way? I've already done something with selenium and didn't got successful...