# Controlling Browser using Python?

Tags: python, browser, webbrowser-control

Is it possible to control a web browser like Firefox using Python?

I would want to do things like

- launch the browser
- force clicks on URLs
- take screenshots

etc.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292817/how-to-automate-browsing-using-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152/automate-firefox-with-python

Comment: By the way, why do you want to do this? Is it to do unit testing of web-based software? Or some other purpose?

Answer (score 26):

[Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/index.html) is a project that comes very close to what you are after. It is really easy to get working in Python with the `selenium.webdriver` subpackage that comes with it. Once upon a time, these were two projects. They've now been unified.

#### Installation

Simple!

```
$ pip install -U selenium
```

#### Usage

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> ff = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> ff.get("http://stackoverflow.com/q/3369073/395287")
>>> ff.save_screenshot("/absolute/path/to/webpage.png")
```

#### Notes

The documentation can be slightly confusing for Selenium, because there are two modes to interact with browsers. As well as the `webdriver` mode, there is the ability to talk to a "standalone Selenium Remote Control server". That approach is what is documented first in the [official documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html), but I would stick with `webdriver` for the simple task here.

Comment: thanks a lot Tim. its installation was much easier than spynner's

Answer (score 10):

If you need to take screenshots, then you need to render the pages. I would recommend to use Selenium (as mentioned by Tim), or then [spynner](https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner).

Here is a sample code of what you need using spynner:

```
import spynner

browser = spynner.Browser()
browser.load("http://stackoverflow.com/q/3369073/")
browser.snapshot().save('file.png')
browser.close()
```

Comment: I really like spynner. Combined with pyquery it allows me to automate a lot of web tasks.

Answer (score 3):

[wxWebConnect](http://www.kirix.com/labs/wxwebconnect.html) is a wxWidgets library for controlling Gecko (Mozilla's rendering engine). Together with [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/), it would allow you to write your own (minimal) web browser in Python, and hence control clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Ag great way to control a browser in Python is to use `PyQt4.QtWebKit`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what do you actually want to achieve. If you need to do some automatic stuff w/out user interference, you can just use underlying engine of the browser, like Gecko or WebKit, w/out loading browser itself. There are ready Python bindings to these engines available.

Browsers themself do not provide this kind of API to outside processes. For Firefox, you would need to inject some browser-side code into chrome, either as extension or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit old but I see no references to [pywebkitgtk](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/), you should give it a try. I developed [spynner](http://code.google.com/p/spynner/) using the [pyqt.qtwebkit](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/pyqt4ref.html) bindings, but programmers who prefer pygtk should try pywebketgtk (which feels more pythonic to me). Note though that Qt bindings are more complete (or at least it was last time I checked).