# Opening and Closing a webpage in browser from Python

Tags: python, html

Is there any way to open a browser window with a specified URL, then close the browser at a later point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use python's builtin [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module for this.

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> url = 'http://www.python.org/'
>>> webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

Comment: Which opens, but doesn't provide for closing.

Comment: You can check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369073/controlling-browser-using-python) for other alternatives.

Comment: @W00t: Can you please explain the context of your problem as to what you are really trying to achieve by opening and closing browser tabs.

Comment: I'm attempting to load a list of sites with a 60 second delay in between, but the sites cannot be open alongside each other.

Comment: ok suppose you open `5 pages` at a delay of `60 seconds` so while closing the webpages you want to close them `one by one` or all at once.

Comment: One by one, as each window cannot be open while another window from my script is open

Comment: So, we can do one thing open the 1st url , do the stuff it has to do and than kill that process using python and after 60 sec repeat the above process with 2nd url.

Comment: clicking q while on the page should do

Answer (score 2):

The [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module, the easiest way to open a browser window, does not provide a way to close a browser window that it has opened.

For this level of control, try the [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) module. It's a bit more involved, but offers more control.

Here's an example they give of opening and closing a page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
assert 'Yahoo' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()
```